# Does Realm Already Support Primitive List or Not?

Tags: java, database, realm, realm-list

I've been waiting for Realm to support List < Primitive > (like List < Long >) and I've just seen that the issue related to this feature has been closed and the comment was that this feature was added at the version 3.0.0 of Realm. ([Realm Issue 1881](https://github.com/realm/realm-core/issues/1881))
The problem is, I am using the version 3.7.2 which is the newest one:

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.7.2"
```

And I'm still not able to compile Realm with a primitive list. So, does Realm already support primitive list or not?

Thanks.

Comment: Realm-Core supports it. Realm-Java 4.0.0 release will support it which is due in about 11 days.

Comment: So how can I use Realm-Core? I thought Realm-Core was inbuilt Realm-Java.

Comment: 11 days?! Awesome!! I will wait for it then. If you want to reply the question with what you comment I can mark it as the correct question. :)

Comment: Because while Realm-Core 3.0.0 supports it, the Java annotation processor and query parser has to follow it.

Comment: Note, that the release might get slightly delayed as we are falling a bit behind that deadline, but primitive array support will definitely be part of Realm Java 4.0. You can follow the progress here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/5031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Realm Java supports lists of primitives since [`4.0.0`](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#enhancements-8).

Here are the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#lists-of-primitives).